# Sum of the first n numbers in prolog

Tags: prolog, turbo-prolog, visual-prolog

Hello can anyone help me compute the sum of the first n numbers. For example n=4 => sum = 10.
So far I've wrote this

```
    predicates
  sum(integer,integer)
clauses

  sum(0,0).
   sum(N,R):-
        N1=N-1,
        sum(N1,R1),
        R=R1+N.
```

This one works but I need another implementation. I don't have any ideas how I could make this differen . Please help

Comment: What happened when you ran your program?

Comment: can you please edit your code to make clear what is comment and what is code? This file wouldn't load/compile as is.

Comment: @ChristianF this appears to be Visual Prolog which uses named sections and allows definition of data types within the `domains` section. It's a little off-standard. The above code is syntactically valid Visual Prolog code (with the exeception of the misspelled "intger").

Comment: I'm using Turbo Prolog. I get the following error : Free variable in expresion R=R+N

Comment: Turbo Prolog is the same as Visual Prolog. Borland bought it many, many years ago from Prolog Development Corp and then sold it back later on. :)

Answer (score 7):

What @mbratch said.

What you're computing is a [*triangular number*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). If your homework is about triangular numbers and not about learning recursive thinking, you can simply compute it thus:

```
triangular_number(N,R) :- R is N * (N+1) / 2 .
```

If, as is more likely, you're learning recursive thought, try this:

```
 sum(N,R) :-    % to compute the triangular number n,
   sum(N,1,0,R) % - invoke the worker predicate with its counter and accumulator properly seeded
   .

 sum(0,_,R,R).     % when the count gets decremented to zero, we're done. Unify the accumulator with the result.
 sum(C,X,T,R) :-   % otherwise,
   C > 0 ,         % - assuming the count is greater than zero
   T1 is T+X ,     % - increment the accumulator
   X1 is X+1 ,     % - increment the current number
   C1 is C-1 ,     % - decrement the count
   sum(C1,X1,T1,R) % - recurse down
   .               % Easy!
```

Edited to add:

Or, if you prefer a count down approach:

```
 sum(N,R) :- sum(N,0,R).

 sum(0,R,R).       % when the count gets decremented to zero, we're done. Unify the accumulator with the result.
 sum(N,T,R) :-     % otherwise,
   N > 0 ,         % - assuming the count is greater than zero
   T1 is T+N ,     % - increment the accumulator
   N1 is N-1 ,     % - decrement the count
   sum(N1,T1,R)    % - recurse down
   .               % Easy!
```

Both of these are *tail-recursive*, meaning that the prolog compiler can turn them into iteration (google "tail recursion optimization" for details).

If you want to eliminate the accumulator, you need to do something like this:

```
sum(0,0).
sum(N,R) :-
  N > 0 ,
  N1 is N-1 ,
  sum(N1,R1) ,
  R is R1+N
  .
```

A little bit simpler, but each recursion consumes another stack frame: given a sufficiently large value for N, execution will fail with a stack overflow.

Comment: I don't understand why you used X and T. I understand the recursive algorithm for the sum but I don't know how to write it in Prolog. If my number is bigger than 1 I add the number to the result and then call sum(number-1).

Comment: @user3043278: I prefer counting up, rather than down. Six of one; a half dozen of the other, as they say. I've added a simple count down version to my answer. Also added something closer to what you originally had with an explanation of why I took the approach I did.

Answer (score 3):

```
sum(N, Sum) :-
    Sum is (N + 1) * N / 2 .
```

Comment: Provide some more detail please.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg: see [Arithmetic progression sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum).

Comment: I believe the answer Nicholas gave already pointed that out. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Since you already got plenty of advice about your code, let me throw in a snippet (a bit off-topic).

Counting, and more generally, aggregating, it's an area where Prolog doesn't shine when compared to other relational,declarative languages (read SQL). But some vendor specific [library](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate) make it much more pleasant:

```
?- aggregate(sum(N),between(1,4,N),S).
S = 10.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the "heart" of your program:

```
sum(N,R):-
    R=R+N,
    N=N-1,
    sum(N,R).
```

The `=/2` predicate (note the `/2` means it accepts 2 arguments) is the *instantiation* predicate, not an assignment, or logical equal. It attempts to unify its arguments to make them the same. So if `N` is anything but `0`, then `R=R+N` will always fail because `R` can never be the same as `R+N`. Likewise for `N=N-1`: it will always fail because `N` and `N-1` can never be the same.

In the case of `=/2` (unification), expressions are *not* evaluated. They are just terms. So if `Y = 1`, then `X = Y + 1` unifies `X` with `1+1` as a term (equivalently written `+(1,1)`).

Because of the above issues, `sum` will always fail.

Numerical assignment of an arithmetic expression is done in Prolog with the `is/2` predicate. Like this:

```
X is Y + 1.
```

This operator *unifies* the value of `X` to be the same as the value of the evaluated expression `Y+1`. In this case, you also cannot have `X is X+1` for the same reason given above: `X` cannot be made the same as `X+1` and Prolog does not allow "re-instantiation" of a variable inside of a clause. So you would need something like, `X1 is X + 1`. Also note that for `is/2` to work, everything in the expression on the right must be previously instantiated. If any variables in the expression on the right do not have a value, you will get an **instantiation error** or, in the case of Turbo Prolog, **Free variable in expression...**.

So you need to use different variables for expression results, and organize the code so that, if using `is/2`, variables in the expression are instantiated.

---

**EDIT**

I understand from Sergey Dymchenko that Turbo Prolog, unlike GNU or SWI, evaluates expressions for `=/2`. So the `=` will work in the given problem. However, the error regarding instantiation (or "free variable") is still caused by the same issue I mentioned above.

Comment: I tried this but still not working sum(N,R):-
    P=R+N,
    N1=N-1,
    sum(N1,P).

Comment: @user3043278 See elements of my answer regarding `=/2` versus `is/2`. Also see my description regarding cause of "Free variable in expression..." First, you need `is` instead of `=`. `=` isn't the right predicate. Secondly, in the order that they exist in your clause, `is` will fail due to an instantiation (free variable) error.

Comment: mbratch, Visual Prolog (and Turbo Prolog) is a funny thing, =/2 is used instead of is/2: see examples at http://progopedia.com/implementation/visual-prolog/

Comment: @SergeyDymchenko wow, that's interesting. It's been a long time since I used Turbo Prolog and I had forgotten that they deviated from the basic standard, which is too bad. The `=/2` versus `is/2` is something quite fundamental. I did try the example you linked to in GNU Prolog for interest and it stack overflowed (after I edited out the Turbo Prolog environment items), probably because it tried to unify with `=/2`, like it's supposed to. But that said, my comments about "Free variable..." still apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(N, N, N).  
sum(M, N, S):-
  N>M,
  X is M+1,
  sum(X, N, T),
  S is M+T.


?- sum(1,5,N).
   N = 15 .
```